# How to unload AngularJS directive when changing templates

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a web app built with AngularJS and it includes various routes/controllers/views/etc.

Several views require directives that I include. I've noticed though that when I change the route and a new template is loaded the directives from the old template continue to be run. Simply creating a directive that logs to console you'll continue to have it logging when the new route is loaded.

Is there a way to avoid this? It seems a bit of a waste of memory.

Comment: That shouldn't happen. Can you please post a plunker with the problem? Maybe there are event listeners or timers you didn't stop listening to when the directive scope\element were destroyed.

Comment: Of course! I was binding to resize and forgot to unbind. Added:
`$scope.$on('$destroy',function()
{
 angular.element($window).unbind('resize');
});`
and all good!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to unbind events bound to within the directive.

For example, if you had a resize event bound to the window you would do the following:

```
$scope.$on('$destroy',function() {
    angular.element($window).unbind('resize')
})
```